# Trying to find a series I started - dragons hibernating

Tags: story-identification, dragons

Trying to find a series I started a couple of years ago. The last book I read ended with a father taking his son into a cave where the dragons were hibernating. The tribe he belonged to looked after the dragons. It was a big secret, as the rest of the world thought they had gone.

The other thing I remember is there was a disgraced "general" that was working with a small group of people as guards for a caravan, and then kind of guards in general for this young woman who had this real head for business.

I realize this isn't much to go on.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Is there anything else you can remember about the series (when did you read it, how old was it, what language was it in, how long was it)? You might be interested in [our guidance](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/31394) on asking story-ID questions.

Comment: thanks. I'll read that. I'm trying to member more. like your name.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/The-Dragons-Path-Dagger-Coin/dp/0316080683?

Comment: I that this ending that I'm remembering was probably the end of the third book. there was also war going on. the caves the dragons are in are nearish to water. I feel like the people watching over them were on a group of islands.

Comment: yes! thanks richard. put that as an answer, and I'm mark as correct. I've going crazy trying to remember. couldn't remember any proper noun to help me find it.

Comment: Don't forget to put an @ in front of the name of someone you want to notify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [The Dragon's Path](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0316080683), part of 'The Dagger and the Coin' series by Daniel Abraham. You've evidently read several books in the series as you're describing incidents from the first book and the third, [The King's Blood](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0316080772)

> Marcus' hero days are behind him. He knows too well that even the smallest war still means somebody's death. When his men are impressed into a doomed army, staying out of a battle he wants no part of requires some unorthodox steps.
>
> Cithrin is an orphan, ward of a banking house. Her job is to smuggle a nation's wealth across a war zone, hiding the gold from both sides. She knows the secret life of commerce like a second language, but the strategies of trade will not defend her from swords.
>
> Geder, sole scion of a noble house, has more interest in philosophy than in swordplay. A poor excuse for a soldier, he is a pawn in these games. No one can predict what he will become.
>
> Falling pebbles can start a landslide. A spat between the Free Cities and the Severed Throne is spiraling out of control. A new player rises from the depths of history, fanning the flames that will sweep the entire region onto The Dragon's Path -- the path to war.

[image]